# How to stat out an awakened player character

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, character-creation

I am thinking of creating a character who is an awakened animal. How would I convert the creature's statblock into one for a player?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This is a homebrew race

The only aspect of the character likely affected by the *awaken* spell is its race. You would not use the creature's statblock, and instead create a homebrew race that is reminiscent of the creature's abilities and traits. Then perhaps you can add racial feats to gain access to more powerful options (even starting at higher levels if access to those racial feats would make more sense immediately).

For details on how to create a homebrew race, see the Dungeon Master's Workshop in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* where there is a section called ["Creating a Race or Subrace"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#CreatingaRaceorSubrace). Additionally, you can see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/127783/41726) for a general idea of how to look for balance, if that is something you are interested in ensuring.