# Is this homebrewed The Chosen One race balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, homebrew-review, races

This is my first time homebrewing a race. I want to know that if it is balance or not.
Also, if not, what should I change to balance it.

> ## Race: The Chosen One
>
> ### The Chosen One Traits
>
> ***Ability Score Increase.*** One ability score of your choice increased by 2.
> ***Age.*** The Chosen One is just a random human who was chosen by the fates. They mature at the same rate, and live to the same age, as a normal human.
> ***Alignment.*** The Chosen One can be any alignment.
> ***Size.*** Your size is Medium.
> ***Speed.*** Your base walking speed is 30 ft.
> ***Languages.*** You speak, read, and write Common.
> ***Proficiency.*** You gain one proficiency of your choice; it can be a skill, weapon, or armor proficiency.
> ***A Little Help From The Fate.*** You can add a d2 bonus to any die roll you make: attack roll, damage roll, ability check, saving throw, etc.. Once you use this feature, you can't use it again until you finish a long rest. At level 5, this bonus increases to a d4.
> ***Protected.*** When you are reduced to 0 hit points but not killed outright, you can drop to 1 hit point instead. You can’t use this feature again until you finish a long rest.
> ***Blessed Attack.*** You can add a d4 damage to one attack that targets only 1 creature/object; this extra damage's type is the same type as the attack's. After you use this trait, you can't use it again until you finish a long rest. At level 4, the extra damage increases to a d6; at level 8, to a d8; at level 12, a d10.

Comment: Worth reading: [How do I evaluate whether my homebrew race is balanced?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/127783/14878)

Comment: @findusl It's suppose to be "you can't use it again until you finish a long rest.", my mistake. I have edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Maybe

It's got too much customization. Play testing will be required to accurately evaluate.

From the Age line, it is clear that this is a Human Variant race. The official Human variant has +1 to two ability scores (player choice) and a Feat (player choice), along with Medium size, Common language, 30 ft speed (all three are standard and will be ignored henceforth). The official Human variant is widely considered stronger than the default Human (no Feat, +1 to all six ability scores).

By comparison, this variant gets +2 to one ability score (player choice), one proficiency (Skill, Weapon, Armor) of the player's choice, a d2 to **any die roll** made for the character (with language that lets it apply to damage rolls) once per long rest that upgrades to d4 at 5th level, the half-orc survival feature, and a once per long rest bonus damage die (for something like *scorching ray* there is an argument that the bonus damage could apply to each ray as long as only one creature is being targeted). The bonus damage is a die so it gets multiplied by Critical Hits.

---

So the ASI is doubled up on the most important stat, a much-desired feature to maximize any build.

It trades away the Human Variant's bonus Feat for a proficiency (one third of a feat), a self-only *bless*, and an emergency damage increase. That combines to about one Feat of benefits. The drawback is that most of that is only usable once per long rest - which might make it balanced across the adventuring day; but like the Paladin class, it will spike impressively.

On paper, it appears balanced. But paper-analysis relies upon assumptions that might not be true in your campaign(s). Play testing will be required to determine if this is actually balanced.

(My gut says "no" but that's not a reliable metric.)

Comment: It seems worth noting that Tasha's adds a rule (optional?) that allows moving around any racial stat bonuses, for all races, so long as they remain distinct.