# Is this homebrew Chaos domain balanced compared to the official subclasses?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, cleric, homebrew-review, domains

I am making a compendium of homebrew Cleric subclasses, spells and feats, but I want to make sure it is actually balanced and there are no glaring loopholes or broken combos with existing feats, spells, and subclasses before I release it. Is this homebrew Chaos Domain balanced compared to the other cleric subclasses?

## Chaos Domain

While most gods create some from of order, others prefer its destruction and embrace entropy and unexpectedness at all times.  Gods of chaos include Eris, Sutr, Zurguth, and Mask, though many clerics worship Chaos itself.

**Domain Spells**

| Level | Spells |
| --- | --- |
| 1st | *Chaos Bolt, Grease* |
| 3rd | *Crown of Madness, Knock* |
| 5th | *Bestow Curse, Summon Lesser Demons* |
| 7th | *Confusion, Hallucinatory Terrain* |
| 9th | *Mislead, Maelstrom* |

**Constant Flux**

Before you roll any attack roll, saving throw, or ability check, you may flip a coin.  On a heads, you gain advantage on the roll, on a tails, you gain disadvantage.

**Cantrip Substitution**

You learn one cantrip of your choice from any spell list, it counts as a cleric cantrip for you.  Whenever you finish a long rest, you may swap it with a different cantrip.

**Channel Divinity: Baleful Transposition**

At 2nd level, as a reaction at any time, including during your turn, you can use your channel divinity and select any creature within 30 feet of yourself.  The creature must make a charisma saving throw.  You and the creature switch positions on a failed save.

**Channel Divinity: Chaotic Casting**

At 6th level, whenever you cast a spell, you can use your channel divinity to roll twice on the Wild Magic table.  Choose which one of the effects you rolled happens.

**Potent Spellcasting**

Starting at 8th level, you add your Wisdom modifier to the damage you deal with any cleric cantrip.

**Random Magic**

At 17th level, as an action, you can choose 12 9th level spells with a casting time of 1 action that lack costly material components.  Assign each a number 1-12.  Roll a d12.  You cast that spell as a cleric spell without expending a spell slot.  Once you use this ability you cannot do so again until you finish a long rest.

Comment: You should include your own commentary on each feature, explaining your concerns about balance. I’m voting to close all of these until you have added more details.

Comment: We need more detail on your thoughts and methods. Where do you feel the problems are in your balancing? Where do you actually need input?

Comment: Please see on meta: [How should I ask about my D&D 5e Homebrew being balanced?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8173/1204) and [How can I ask a good homebrew review question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8121/1204). It's generally desired that you don't just go "here's a feature, is it balanced?" but instead walk us through the specific aims and doubts you have. Have you playtested it and found anything concerning in your playtests? That's useful to do and talk alk about. See: [How do I evaluate whether my homebrew race is balanced?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/127783/1204)

Answer (score 2):

### This feels quite powerful.

I'll go over the abilities one at a time:

#### Constant Flux

There is 0% reason not to use this on any roll you would make with Disadvantage, as it gives you a 50% chance to cancel it for free. There is 0% reason to ever use this in any other situation, since you're either getting nothing from it or actively reducing your odds.

The end result is that it's very powerful but also not going to be used the way you think it is.

#### Cantrip Substitution

This is probably fine, and suitable for a Chaos cleric.

#### Channel Divinity: Baleful Transposition

This is again very powerful. Being able to swap places with an enemy lets you do things like transport them in the middle of your party to be mauled on at level 2. At higher levels, it lets you move yourself into dangerous terrain and then swap positions with them, like when you have flight and move over a cliff, or are yourself resistant to the negative effect like transposing an Undead into a Hallowed area. Or an enemy into a jail cell, or whatever. Lots of creative ways to abuse this.

#### Chaotic Casting

This is probably fine, if not mostly pointless. Half the entries on the Wild Magic table don't do anything meaningful (and most of the others screw you over), so I doubt anyone would really be using this if it means giving up Baleful Transposition.

#### Potent Spellcasting

Not sure what this has to do with chaos magic, but there's more classes that get this and cleric cantrips aren't that powerful for the most part.

#### Random Magic

I would outright ban this ability from my games. Not because it's that powerful (it potentially is, since it gives you a second 9th level spell) but because resolving this would take **way** too long. Selecting 12 9th level spells in the middle of a situation just breaks immersion too much.

If you want something like this, it really needs to be a set list of spells that you roll against, to cut down on the time taken. Also I'd add a spell slot cost to it, because two 9th level spells per day (even if one is random) is something nobody gets without an Epic Boon.

(And as a bit of personal opinion; the random magic is very fitting and I'd consider finding a way to make it a core part of this domain instead of the capstone.)

Comment: Potent spellcasting and the ability to get eldritch blast is quite powerful

Comment: @SeriousBri It depends on if it's added to each bolt, in which case it's as good as (and stacks with) Agonizing Blast, which could be *very* powerful, or if it's just once per cast.

Comment: You may wish to review your opinion on Potent Spellcasting. Large parts of the table are positive or neutral. Only a small percentage of it is outright negative. Thus, the notion of getting 2 rolls on the table very enticing.