# When is something overpowered?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance

There are over a 500 questions on this site that ask if this or that is overpowered.

**By what criteria would you determine if something is overpowered?** Can this only be resolved in specific narrow context where all the circumstances and conditions are known, or is there any a generally applicable framework to determine if something is overpowered? Without such a framework, how can these questions even be answered? (I know, this is a list of questions: the primary one I want answered is the one of the title).

As this only makes sense in the context of a given game system, I'm asking specifically for D&D 5e here.

Comment: Hi @goodguy5, thanks for the hint. Will update (and learned something about search)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I'm not sure I agree - personally, this feels more like a meta question, because we have many questions about if something is overpowered, and many answers. How do we as a community, decide that those answers are right and valid?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I am explictly not asking for opinions, but for measurable criteria to determine if something is overpowered. For example, the game suggests a balance in the form of adequate CRs (even if not an exact science), that could be a starting point.

Comment: Related: "[What are the standards for balance questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4976)" | "[Where Can We Ask "Is This Item/Spell/Ability Fair" Questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6544)" | "[How can we address questions about homebrew balance?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9948)" | "[Are "is this balanced" questions on-topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7952)" | "[How do I evaluate whether my homebrew race is balanced?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/127783)". That last one may be a duplicate

Comment: That said, I'll take KRyan's dupe closure as a good target.

Comment: @Exempt-Medic thank you for the links!